# What does Pycharm do when a new project and new interpreter is created / selected? (Skeleton?)

Tags: python, pycharm

So, other than indexing, more processes that takes hours start when I create a new porject and I select conda interpreter. Below is a snapshot. What are these processes, and do they consume space when done?

[image]

Comment: A skeleton is something that generates with the project. So:everything in there to start a new django app, website, python library, whatever. Basic readme, setup.py, models.py and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyCharm runs `generator3.py` script (from `<pycharm_installation_folder>\helpers\`) to construct Python stubs for binary modules, see `~\.PyCharm<VERSION>\system\python_stubs\...`. This way IDE will be able to show a relevant completion for them.

There is an idea to pregenerate and bundle stubs for Anaconda with PyCharm, it is currently in the development https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-34604 but it is not yet ready.

If you don't need everything from base Anaconda - try conda environments and install only requirements. This way it will be less work for IDE.

Comment: If I make an interpreter available to all projects, would that save work when I create a new project and choose that interpreter for it?

Comment: That's correct, PyCharm will reuse the binary stubs.